# Programmatically add image to media gallery in Magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript, gallery-image

I am looking at [this article](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_gallery.html) on the Gallery API in Magento2. I am testing the code samples in my browser

```
var api = $('[data-gallery-role="gallery"]').data('gallery');
```

However, this returns `undefined`... The first part *does* return an element

```
$('[data-gallery-role="gallery"]')
```

The later part is what seems to not be working as expected. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: I assume I have to [initialize](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html#init_phtml) it first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. We are using a custom theme on this project, so navigating to

```
custom-theme-dir/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml
```

I found

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
           ...
```

So in my case the code to access the fotorama api is

```
var fotorama = jQuery('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder').data('gallery');
```